# How does React.useState(<initialState>) update with <initialState> updates?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```js
function Count() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const [count2] = React.useState(count)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>+</button>
      <p>count: {count}</p> // does update
      <p>count 2: {count2}</p>. // does not update
    </div>
  )
}
```

Why does `count2` not update when `count` updates after `<button>` is clicked?

I thought only lazy initialised states (e.g. `React.useState(() => count)`) are not updated on component re-renders.

Comment: You don't have a setter for count2.

Comment: Because that `setCount` is only initiated for `count1`. If you need to update `count2`, you need another `setState` for count2: `const [count2, setCount2] = React.useState(0)`. Then you can use `setCount2(another_number)` to update `count2`. The initial state is **not** reactive. It is just a value copied at the start of `useState`; after that, React should not revisit that value, but rely on `setState` calls to update the value.

Comment: `useState` would be pretty useless if every render re-initialized it.  It only gets re-initialized when the component is entirely unloaded from memory (like when navigating away to a different route) and then a new instance of the component is loaded (when navigating back).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `setCount2` to update `count2` using a `useEffect` having dependency on `count`.

```
function Count() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [count2, setCount2] = React.useState(count);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount2(count);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>+</button>
      <p>count: {count}</p> 
      <p>count 2: {count2}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If it solve your question, please kindly mark it as accepted by clicking on the green tick mark for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a messy solution to your problem, Messy in terms that it could be improved but as of right now I cannot think of any better solutions than this.

```js
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [count2, setCount2] = React.useState(count);

  const changeStateForCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setCount2(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={changeStateForCount}>+</button>
      <p>count: {count}</p> {/* does update */}
      <p>count 2: {count2}</p>. {/* does not update */}
    </div>
  );
}
```